# How to permanently hide recycle view items

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, stack-overflow

I am using android studio with firebase realtime data base. I wish to hide an item in recycler view based on certain condition, for that I have used `holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` as some people pointed here in stack,  and items disappeared correctly as I wished, but when I returned back to home after pressing back button I noticed that all the hidden items reappeared. I want the items to permanently  hidden even after login out and login in.  How to attain such a behavior?

In my project I am trying to collect the enquiry from buyers and I am trying to display on sellers activity. These enquires are fetched in recycler view. if the seller click a particular enquiry and expresses interest that enquiry I want to hide  in his enquiry list. There is no need for him to see that enquiry again and again. (I don't want that enquiry  to be removed completely from data base so other sellers can see that). I just want to hide that enquiry for the seller who already expressed interest.

I used this method to fetch data from my data base and display in my fragment using recycler view:

```
private void getEnquires(){

    query=RootRef.child("Enquires");

    // EnquiryModelClass is my model class

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<EnquiryModelClass> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<EnquiryModelClass>()
                    .setQuery(query,EnquiryModelClass.class)
                    .build();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EnquiryModelClass,EnquiryListViewHolder> adapter
            =new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EnquiryModelClass, EnquiryListViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EnquiryListViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull EnquiryModelClass model) {

            final String messageId = getRef(position).getKey();

            RootRef.child("Enquires").child(messageId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    final String  returnBuyerIDs=snapshot.child("buyerId").getValue().toString(); // here I am fetching id of the person who send the enquiry from my database

                    holder.EnquiryMessage.setText("You have an enquiry on ");

                    holder.eqDate.setText( model.getDate());
                    holder.eqTime.setText(",at:"+ model.getTime());

                    holder.Viewmore.setText("ViewMore ");

                    holder.Viewmore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // I had put a button in recycler view upon clicking on the item , it has to take me to next activity and hide current item
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), FirstReplyActivity.class); // video 46
                            chatIntent.putExtra("seller_id", SellerUserId);
                            chatIntent.putExtra("enquiry_message_id", messageId);
                            chatIntent.putExtra("buyer_user_id", returnBuyerIDs);//
                            chatIntent.putExtra("buyer_enquiry_message", model.getEnquiryMessage());//
                            chatIntent.putExtra("buyer_user_name", model.getCustomerName());
                            chatIntent.putExtra("enquiryDate", model.getDate());
                            chatIntent.putExtra("enquiryTime", model.getTime());

                            startActivity(chatIntent);

                         holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // by using this I try to hide the particular view
```

holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0,0)); // for removing spaces , but now my app is crushing

```
                        }
                    });
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public EnquiryListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.enquirylist_layout_for_recycler, viewGroup, false);
            EnquiryListViewHolder viewHolder = new EnquiryListViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };

    EnqList10km.setAdapter(adapter); 
    adapter.startListening();

}
```

And my Holder class

```
public static class EnquiryListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView  eqDate,eqTime, EnquiryMessage;
        Button Viewmore;
        public EnquiryListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            eqDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateEq);
            eqTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeEq);
            EnquiryMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.enquiry);
            Viewmore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewmore);


        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to store the information in the logic that decides what data to load into the adapter.

Comment: I hear you, and am sorry for the struggle. I'd love to help (which is why we're all here), but there isn't enough information in the question right now to do so. If the hidden items are reappearing, the code isn't working as intended. If you edit the question to show the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can try to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelenIn my project I am trying to collect the enquiry from buyers and I am trying to display on sellers activity. These enquires are fetched in recycler view. if the seller click a particular enquiry and expresses interest that enquiry I want to hide  in his enquiry list. There is no need for him to see that enquiry again and again. (I don't want that enquiry  to be removed completely from data base so other sellers can see that). I just want to hide that enquiry for the seller who already expressed interest

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Right now you're only hiding the view in the `onClick` handler: `holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. But when the view reloads, nothing is clicked, so the `onClick` handler isn't rerun. You'll need to store the fact that the user clicked on a certain item somewhere (either shared preferences or in the database), and then restore it from there when the list is reloaded.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the information. A I added the details please unblock my question

Comment: I already voted to reopen. I also left a comment of how to address your problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Still it is blocked..shall I delete question and put as a new question?

Comment: Did you see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67794198/how-to-permanently-hide-recycle-view-items?noredirect=1#comment119863646_67794198) on how to solve the issue? Did you give that a try already?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am working on  it ,  I have limited time as I lost my job I am doing some commercial tax works for my living, in between I am doing this work. Now I am facing one more problem,even though the item is hiding it is leaving a blank space, for that I found some solutions I am implementing that. I have only one node in firebase which stores all enquires from buyers from that I am fetching that enquires for displaying in sellers page,as you told if I save that clicked information I can retrieve that items but for deleting that item for an individual seller I have find another sol

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen   ....After   holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  I had put  holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0,0)) ; for removing spaces.. [Kindly see my code]   but now my app is crashing ..can you able to tell why it is crushing??

Comment: It's hard to say why the app is crashing (not "crushing" btw) without seeing the error. But at this point you've moved on past your original question, and have a new problem, so I recommend posting a new question for that, with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (including the minimal code, the error message and its stack trace).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok . I will put as a separate question ..Kindly see my earlier comment also, am I right I have to save separate enquiry information for every seller right ?? but I think that will create a big storage issue right ??

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , can you able to see my new question .  Removing blank blank spaces in recycler view while hiding an item crashing app

Comment: I did no such thing on your new question, but somebody else did. If you disagree with its closing, I recommend posting to meta.stackoverflow.com with a clear explanation of why you disagree.